# Text Editor recommendations for django shell (python manage.py shell)

Tags: linux, python, text-editor, django

When performing debugging or adding data to my database from CSV files I rely on the django shell (python manage.py shell). I used this during development on a Windows PC and although, I hated using it it was somewhat manageable. I could get back to multilined code for example.

As I am switching to production, I am now running on a Linux Server. The default editor here for the shell is simply unusable. I switched to ipython and at least I can write executable code now but ipython editor seems to have a compatibility problem. If I want to look at my database queryset, I get: TypeError: str returned non-string (type NoneType) which seems to be a problem with repr(obj).

Can anyone recommend an editor or does anyone know how to find out which one I was using before on windows? Thanks and best.